# Entering then re-entering the US on F1 before the start of the program stated on I-20

Tags: esta, us-visa-waiver-program, f1-visas

I have a valid F1 visa and my I-20 has a program start date of August 5th. My I-20 states that I can enter the US starting July 5th. I have my flights booked to enter the US on July 10Th. I will then leave the US to visit Panama with some friends on July 12Th and then return to the US on July 17Th. I learned that a travel signature is required on the I-20 page 2 in order to leave and re-enter the US. I have contacted the University to get the travel endorsement signature but they told me they don't provide such signature before the start of the program and that I shouldn't travel to Panama to avoid problems when reentering the US.

Since I'm a citizen of Europe, is it possible for me to apply for Esta. Ask the immigration officer to use the visa waver program instead of the F1 when entering the first time on July 10Th. Then enter with the F1 visa and i-20 when I return from Panama on July 17Th?

Comment: There is nothing I have seen in our immigration/visa rules that preclude you from doing exactly that. I do not have a reference so will not post as an answer however I know it is totally acceptable. Your purpose for entering on the ESTA will then be for a college visit which is allowed on B visa and hence ESTA..

Comment: Yeah, it sounds OK to me. Just make sure to use the kiosk when enterng on the VWP and don't use the kiosk when you enter on the student visa.